# Why my jquery code is not able to find the button inside list item?

Tags: jquery

I have this html. I am trying to show the hidden cancel button of a given li.
But not sure why my code is not working.
I find the right li element but I am not able to show the hidden Cancel button inside the selected li item.

Here is my coude:

```
var $li = $('.qq-upload-list li.qq-upload-fail').eq(id); //I pass 0 based index correctly
if ($li != null && $li != undefined) {
   $li.find('.qq-upload-cancel').show();                            
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="qq-upload-list">
<li class=" qq-upload-fail">
<div class="qq-progress-bar" style="display: none; width: 100%;"></div>
<span class="qq-upload-spinner" style="display: none;"></span>
<span class="qq-upload-finished"></span>
<a class="qq-upload-cancel" href="#" style="display: none;">Cancel</a>
<a class="qq-upload-retry" href="#">Retry</a>
<a class="qq-upload-delete" href="#">Delete</a>
<span class="qq-upload-status-text">Upload failed</span>
</li>
<li class=" qq-upload-fail">..</li>
</ul>
```

**UPDATE:**
I found the issue. The above html is generated dynamically by code. But the code excutes after the event I was handling. Once I move the code to the right event handler all looks good.

Comment: Even though the answers (correctly) suggest to use `.eq(0)`, even easier is it to just remove the `.eq(...)` call (I don't see a reason why you need it here).

Comment: @FelixKling, OP has more than 1 `li` and might have more `.qq-upload-cancel`, I suggested also using `:first`

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery [**eq()**](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) is zero based, you might want to use `eq(0)` instead of `eq(1)`.

**Please note** that jQuery objects are always `!= null` && `!= undefined`, you might want to check for length there. Like `if($li && $li.length){`

Try with:

```
var $li = $('.qq-upload-list li.qq-upload-fail').eq(0);
```

**Option**, use [**:first**](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/)

```
var $li = $('.qq-upload-list li.qq-upload-fail:first');
```

Comment: parameter for eq() is not the issue. I pass the right index. I told that I find the correct li item.

Comment: I can't use first. It is a callback where I get the id (index of the li) as a return value.

Comment: @kheya, `:first` was a suggestion based on your first post. I don't see more problems in your code. Please check this fiddle and reproduce your problem in it: http://jsfiddle.net/J9r2L

Answer (score 1):

Since [eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) is `0-based` index, you need to change:

```
var $li = $('.qq-upload-list li.qq-upload-fail').eq(1);
```

to:

```
var $li = $('.qq-upload-list li.qq-upload-fail').eq(0);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wVC64/)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this,

```
$('.qq-upload-list li.qq-upload-fail').find('.qq-upload-cancel').show();
```

To show the third cancel button,

```
 var $li = $('.qq-upload-list > li.qq-upload-fail').eq( 2 ); //I pass 0 based index correctly
 $li.children('a.qq-upload-cancel').show();
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/7xz7Y/

Comment: which li you are modifying? There can be 5 li items all having qq-upload-fail class. How do I show the cancel button of the third li?